# How do I use the multiply line results from query or filter to get other values from an unsorted sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to take the results of a filter with multiple lines and use that results to acquire info from another sheet. Specifically, I'm trying to acquire `Quantities` in `Customer Order` sheet using `Purchase ID` from `Total Cost` sheet and the `Unit Prices` in the `Database` sheet through the `Product Names` in `Customer Orders` sheet. I than multiple the values in this case Quantity * Unit Price = Total Cost. Here is a visual on what I'm trying to do.

Example:

Sheet 'Total Cost'

```
Purchase ID  Total Cost  Should be
BH2          $48.00      $59.00
KP3          $7.00       $52.00
```

Get Purchase ID from column A

Sheet 'Customer Orders'

```
Product Name  Quality   Purchase ID
Black Hats    12        BH2
Brown Shoes   1         BH2
Trimmers      7         BH2
Black Hats    11        KP3
Brown Shoes   2         KP3
```

Get Quantities that match the Purchase ID from the Customer Orders sheet
Get Product Names from Customer Orders using the Purchase ID

Sheet 'Database'

```
Product Name    Unit Price
Black Hats      $4.00
Pink Hats       $3.00
Blue Hats       $5.00
Purple Hats     $7.00
Brown Shoes     $4.00
Trimmers        $1.00
```

Use the Product Names from Customer Orders through the use of the Purchase ID to acquire the Unit Prices from the Database sheet

Formulas I have tried:

This one gives the list of names but I can't seem to reuse the array of names to get the prices of all the names in the array from the Database

```
Result  Formula                             
$4.00   =QUERY(Database!A2:B,"select B where A = '"&QUERY('Customer Orders'!A2:C, 
        "select A where C = '"&$A2&"'",0)&"'")
```

I can pull the first quantity in the list but I need all the quantities matching A2 which is BH2 in this case. Which should be the quanities 12, 1 and, 7

```
Result  Formula                             
12      =INDEX('Customer Orders'!$A$2:$B,MATCH(A2,'Customer Orders'!C2:C,0),2)
```

I can get the list of names from the Customer Orders sheets but plugging the formula into another formula yeilds the same as the QUERY example.

```
Result       Formula
Black Hats   =FILTER('Customer Orders'!A2:A,'Customer Orders'!C2:C = A2)
Brown Shoes
Trimmers

Result       Formula
$4.00        =QUERY(Database!A2:B,"select B where A = '"&
             FILTER('Customer Orders'!A2:A,'Customer Orders'!C2:C = A2)&"'")
```

The end result of my formulas is this but it doesn't use any more than the first entry. The output should be `$59.00`

```
Result           Formula
$48.00           =INDEX(Database!$A$2:$C,MATCH(INDEX('Customer Orders'!$A$2:$B,
                  MATCH(A2,'Customer Orders'!C2:C,0),1),Database!$A$2:$A,0),2) * 
                  INDEX('Customer Orders'!$A$2:$B,MATCH(A2,'Customer Orders'!C2:C,0),2)
```

How I'm currently thinking the steps could go.

> Step 1    Get Purchase ID from column A
>   Step 2    Get Quantities that match the Purchase ID from the Customer Orders sheet
>   Step 3    Get Product Names from Customer Orders using the Purchase ID
>   Step 4    Use the Product Names to acquire the Unit Prices from the Database sheet
>   Step 5    Quantity * Unit Price = Total Cost

Spreadsheets with the examples I'm shown here.

> Editable: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUizkk4OxSUfeNHh-cvhmFCTUNDRAAuOMYmQcqTBmKQ/edit?usp=sharing)
>   Read only: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5hYWt51aApBLCFFZaS_r5ZToGG6OWjwjhS6m4YyrwE/edit?usp=sharing)

I hope all of this makes sense. I'll try and answer any questions I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY('Customer Orders'!$A$2:$C, 
                         "select B where C ='"&A2&"'", 0)} *
                  {ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(
                   QUERY('Customer Orders'!$A$2:$C, 
                         "select A where C ='"&A2&"'", 0),
                   Database!$A$2:$B,2,0))}))
```

[image: 4]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your time and your knowledge on this topic <3.